# not able to assign value to class function using constructor

Tags: c++

I am having issue in assigning value to the class functions.
I am trying to assign the value using dqr constructor but the values are not passed to the build  member function of the class dqr.
        The error it is showing is segmentation fault.

```
class dqr{
    int block_size;
    int *blocks;
    public:  
    dqr(int input[], int);   
    void build(int input[], int n);
    void update(int input[],int,int , int);

    };
     dqr::dqr(int input[], int n){

        int block_size=(sqrt(n));
        cout<<"block Size :"<<block_size;
        int *blocks=new int[block_size];
    } 
    void dqr::build(int input[], int n ){
        for(int i=0;i<(n-1);i++){
            blocks[i/block_size]+=input[i];}
    for(int i=0;i<block_size;i++){
       cout<<blocks[i];
    } }
    int main() 
    {
        int input[] = {1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10};
        int n = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
        dqr d(input, n);
        d.build(input,n);

        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: You create **local** variables in your constructor, which just happen to have the same names as your **member** variables. Local variables shadow member ones, and you only ever set your local variables.

Comment: @MohdZaid: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: What's the point in passing the `input` argument to the class constructor???

Comment: Thanks.. I got it now.

Comment: @goodvibration Then how should I  initialize the value member variables.

Comment: @ P.W. It is sublime.

Comment: @MohdZaid: Sublime is an IDE. Asking for compiler name because some compilers warn you if you make this kind of mistake.

Comment: @P.W  Its g++.. and os is ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is this line in the constructor:

```
int *blocks=new int[block_size];
```

The pointer `int *blocks` is not the same as the member pointer `int *blocks`. What happens is that you create a local pointer called `blocks` in the constructor which dies as soon as you leave the scope of the constructor. Unfortunately, you have already allocated memory in the heap which that local pointer points to. But this memory is not released when the local pointer dies and you have a leak.

You have the same problem with `int block_size` which you also re-create as local variable in the constructor.

Your constructor should look like this:

```
dqr(int input[], int n)
{
    block_size = sqrt(n); //using the member variable block_size.
    std::cout<< "block Size :" << block_size <<std::endl;
    blocks = new int[block_size]; //using the member pointer blocks.
}
```

I'm still not quite sure why you get the square root of `n` as your new block size, but I guess that's part of your design.

Also don't forget to clear the memory in the destructor. As a matter of fact this is why we use smart pointers. In your case, a [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) would be the best option.

Example code: https://rextester.com/CGFQQ92378

Comment: I am trying to implement the square root decomposiition technique.

Comment: aah ok, fair enough. For future reference, try to use smart pointers. A unique_ptr can have the same size as a raw pointer and you won't have to worry about memory being accidentally shared or released.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of segmentation fault is in below code.

```
 dqr::dqr(int input[], int n){

    int block_size=(sqrt(n));
    cout<<"block Size :"<<block_size;
    int *blocks=new int[block_size];
}
```

blocks variable declare as a local variable. so in the build function's blocks variable not assigned in heap memory( dynamic allocate ).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GCC compiler for C++, there is a compiler option that warns you when you have a declare local variable that shadows a class variable. It is `-Wshadow`.

Compiling with this option gives you the following warnings:

```
warning: declaration of 'block_size' shadows a member of 'dqr' [-Wshadow]    
          int block_size=(sqrt(n));    
              ^~~~~~~~~~

<source>:7:9: note: shadowed declaration is here    
     int block_size;    
         ^~~~~~~~~~

<source>:19:15: warning: declaration of 'blocks' shadows a member of 'dqr' [-Wshadow]    
          int* blocks=new int[block_size];    
               ^~~~~~

<source>:8:10: note: shadowed declaration is here
     int *blocks;
          ^~~~~~
```

See **[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/DHa9TV)**.

From the above warnings you will know that you will have to replace the above two lines and actually initialize the class variables in the following manner:

```
block_size = (sqrt(n));

blocks = new int[block_size];
```